# Can LAMP and Ruby on Rails run together on the same VPS server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache

Now , I have a LAMP and run a codeigniter website very well on a VPS (512M) .
another site i want to built it on Rails .
How could i do? is there any recommend tutorials ?
I'm afraid the memory is too tight . because my vps only has about 256M memory now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run using Passenger. It will compile an apache module that you can then use to run Rails websites. You can also use any other approach such as Unicorn.
512M of RAM is not a lot, but for a smaller Rails app it should be enough, especially if you fiddle with the settings a bit. I used to have a 512M VPS and I did occasionally experience crashes because the VPS ran out of RAM, so be wary of this. With a small VPS nginx would probably a better option as opposed to apache.